# RPI Zero as Keyboard: Convert key codes from SHOWKEY to write into /dev/hidg0 HID packet

Tags: pi-zero-w, keyboard, bash, php, hid

I'm using RPI Zero W as keyboard gadget. It's supposed to act as keyboard getaway from Bluetooth keyboard to USB keyboard. I'm running "showkey" shell command process giving me codes of just pressed keys.

I can get pressed key codes in one of the flowing ways:

`# showkey -k // press "a" key
keycode  30 press
keycode  30 release`

OR

`# showkey -s // press "a" key
0x1e
0x9e`

As a final result to send to /dev/hidg0 I need to form a 8-byte HID packet. For the "a" key press it looks like 
`"\0\0\x4\0\0\0\0\0"`.

**Could you please advice how such `"showkey"` codes can be converted into such binary(?) HID packet?** My attempts so convert values between HEX, DEC, ASCII, and Binary, are all failed.

I'm dealing with PHP script, so ideally, I would prefer to do just something like 
`file_put_contents('/dev/hidg0', "\0\0\x4\0\0\0\0\0");`

or I can send a common shell call:

`echo -ne "\0\0\x4\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0`

UPD: Keyboard is QWERTY.

UPD: PI Zero W has Wifi and Bluetooth. Incoming key codes come from Bluetooth keyboard.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fastest solution appeared to be manual test and compare of all the keys one-by-one.